# how to convert parameter string as column or known object in bootstrap datatable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

````
in javascript file:
```
function onSearch(filter, data, parameter) {
    this.filter = filter;
    var row = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            var json = JSON.parse(msg.d);
            var html = "";
            $.each(json, function (index, obj) {
                //html += ""
                //    + "" + row.toString() + ""
                //    + "" + obj.Material_No + ""
                //    + "" + obj.Material_Name + ""
                //    + "";
                html += parameter;
                row++;
            });
            var table = $('#tbDetails').DataTable();
            table.destroy();
            $("#tbDetails tbody").html(html);
            $('#tbDetails').DataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                "order": [[0, "asc"]]
            });

            $('#myModal-1').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        }
        
    });

    return false;
};
```
````

in html file :

````
```
var parameter = ""
+ "" + row.toString() + ""
+ "" + obj.Material_No + ""
+ "" + obj.Material_Name + ""
+ "";
onSearch(filter, data, parameter);
```
````

Please help, i want to the variable parameter to known object, as i comment code before

Answer (score 0):

You want to tell `onSearch` how to format the data that it fetches, but you can't reference `row` and `obj` directly since they're not available until the network call completes. What you're looking for is a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). You're actually already using callbacks - you pass a callback function as the second argument to `$.each`, and the `success` parameter of `$.ajax`.

You'll need to change `onSearch` to accept a callback function as the third parameter, and then pass it when you call `onSearch`, something like:

```js
function onSearch(filter, data, callback) {
  // ...
  $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function (msg) {
      var json = JSON.parse(msg.d);
      var html = callback(json);
      // ...
    },
  });
}

onSearch(filter, data, function (json) {
  var html = "";

  $.each(json, function (index, obj) {
    html += ""
    + "" + obj.toString() + ""
    + "" + obj.Material_No + ""
    + "" + obj.Material_Name + ""
    + "";
  });

  return html;
});
```

There's no variable named `row`, so I'm assuming that should be `obj`. You may need to edit accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, but i have error like this:


function onSearch(filter, data, callback) {
  // ...
  $.ajax({ --> **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: To use `$`, you need to include jQuery on your page. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Oh sure, already. As my comment code before
     $.each(json, function (index, obj) {
                html += ""
                    + "" + row.toString() + ""
                    + "" + obj.Material_No + ""
                    + "" + obj.Material_Name + ""
                    + "";
                row++;
            });
it's running well. But, i want to replace this code by parameter. So, variable html become html+=paramater;